# Chrome does not show all of the inline JS code in the debugger window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug some inline JS code using chrome

However, Chrome only shows me part of the code

[image]

It appears with yellow background and only part of the code is shown.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debug JS in chrome, you must go to source tab.[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Source tab

As mentioned already, you can look at the Sources tab in Chrome. In Sources, if you open the HTML file in which the script is inlined, you should be able to add debug  points to the script.

***However*** this does not  always work. It depends when your inlined script is added to your HTML file. For cases where the inlined script is added after the HTML is loaded, you may want to try the steps below. In my case, I am using PreloadJS with XHR enabled. This is why the script is inlined after the HTML document is loaded. This causes a **portion of** the script to show in the Elements tab, as its now part of the DOM, but in the Sources tab, the HTML file looks the same as when it was initially loaded.

#### Name your script

I found that an ideal way to solve this issue is to provide a name for your inlined script using the `sourceURL` comment. You can find info on this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Debug_eval_sources) and by Googling.

Essentially just add the following line on a new line at the end of your script:

```
//# sourceURL=someScript.js;
```

#### Use `debugger;` statements:

If you dont want  to name your script, you can force Chrome to open your script in the debugger by adding `debugger;` somewhere in your script and reloading the page with Dev Tools open. Once this line is hit your code will be opened in the debugger.

Comment: So if you can't modify the script, it sounds like you're out of luck. Chrome should just let you jump from the script in the Elements tab to the script in the Sources tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your script in the following way. Then it becomes available in the list of files as a separate entry.

```
<script>
    //# sourceURL=name_this_script.js
    ...
</script>
```